# Check a value exists in array from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an array like this in my twig

```
array:19 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "view_subscription_plan"
    "Description" => "View subscription plan"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "view_subscription_period"
    "Description" => "View subscription period"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "view_subscription_details"
    "Description" => "View subscription details"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "create_department"
    "Description" => "Create Department"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "edit_department"
    "Description" => "Edit Department"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "view_department"
    "Description" => "View Department"
  ]
  6 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "delete_department"
    "Description" => "Delete Department"
  ]
  7 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "create_division"
    "Description" => "Create Division"
  ]
  8 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "edit_division"
    "Description" => "Edit Division"
  ]
  9 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "view_division"
    "Description" => "View Division"
  ]
  10 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "delete_division"
    "Description" => "Delete Division"
  ]
  11 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "create_basic_info"
    "Description" => "Create employee basic info"
  ]
  12 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "edit_basic_info"
    "Description" => "Edit employee basic info"
  ]
  13 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "view_basic_info"
    "Description" => "View employee basic info"
  ]
  14 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "delete_basic_info"
    "Description" => "Delete employee basic info"
  ]
  15 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "create_salary"
    "Description" => "Create Salary"
  ]
  16 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "edit_salary"
    "Description" => "Edit Salary"
  ]
  17 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "view_salary"
    "Description" => "View Salary"
  ]
  18 => array:2 [
    "Title" => "delete_salary"
    "Description" => "Delete Salary"
  ]
]
```

I want to check whether a value exists in this array. Something very similar to in_array in PHP. **I don't want to check a key exists**. **This array is dynamic**. the array given above is a dumped version of symfony.

Comment: Please don't use all-caps in normal text. It's the equivalent of shouting in writing. check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 82):

If you want to check if value exists (same as `in_array()` in PHP):

```
{% if value in array %}
```

To check if key exists:

```
{% if key in array|keys %}
```

Comment: not working in my case

Comment: The problem is that you have a nested array, so the solution provided by Kamil Adryjanek won't work in your case. If possible, I recommend you to move this logic to the PHP code, where it should be easy to implement and pass to the Twig template the variable that indicates if the value is present or not.

Comment: it works for me
`{% set negrito = 'Negrito' in box.formats ? 'yes' : 'no' %}`

Comment: Following works :
`{% set array = [{ k: 'key', v: 'value' }] %}
{{ { k: 'key', v: 'value' } in array ? 'ok' : 'ko' }}`